# Execute bash script via Node.js and include command line parameters

Tags: node.js, bash, command-line-arguments, spawn

I'm trying to execute a bash script from a Node application, which I have previously done successfully via:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('bash', [pathToScript], {
    stdio: 'ignore',
    detached: true
}).unref();
```

It's important that I do it this way, because the script needs to continue to execute, even if/when the application is stopped.

Now, the script I need to execute requires an input value to be provided on the command line, ie.

```
./myScript.sh hello
```

But I cannot figure out how to pass this into the spawn call. I have tried the following, with no luck

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn('bash', [pathToScript + '' + params], {
    stdio: 'ignore',
    detached: true
}).unref();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The second parameter in spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options) is an array of arguments to pass to the command. So I think you almost have it but instead of concating the params to the path pass them in as an array:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var params = ['pathToScript','run', '-silent'];
spawn('bash', params, {
    stdio: 'ignore',
    detached: true
}).unref();
```

Comment: That's done the trick, thank you!